# Build docker image with nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have static html / AngularJS file. I am going to launch web server with nginx inside docker image.
How can I build docker image from these html / Js files and configure nginx server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have this files :

```
- myApp/
    - index.html
    - script.js
```

You need to launch nginx :

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -v /pathTo/myApp:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx
```

And then access to with http://localhost:8080

More information on [nginx docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)

Comment: Thanks Mathieu - I launched nginx, but it says:
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Can you show me exactly what command do you use, and what is your file structure please.

Comment: sorry my late reply:
- myApp
index.dev.html
index.html
bower_components.....

I used: docker run -p 8080:80 -v /pathTo/myApp:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx - something same as what you provided.

Comment: Have you change  `/pathTo/myApp` to your real path ? Try with a simple html page to ensure it's working.

Comment: Yes. I did. I gave absolute path to myApp. I am working on macOS env, So I used:
docker run -p 8080:80 -v /absolute/path/To/myApp:/usr/local/nginx/html:ro -d nginx    
But it says "Welcome to nginx" - not my html, just nginx default html.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe because it's different on macOS ? Have you tried with a simple index.html ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work, despite I've changed the path of html to macOS's one.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

Step 1 :

You need to create docker file inside the project root.

```
- myApp/
    - Dockerfile
```

inside the Docker file add below code

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Step 2:

build your project in production mode

Step 3 :

```
docker login

docker build -t <your registry or image location> .

docker run --name <your project name > -d -p 8080:81 <your registry or image location>

docker push <your registry or image location>
```

Comment: What is the copy destination in Dockerfile if I use Macos env?