# Build NextJS Docker image with nginx server

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

I am new to docker and trying to learn it by it's [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image). AS i need to create a NextJS build using docker image for nginx server i have followed the below process.

1. Install the `nginx`
2. [Seeding the port `80 to 3000` in the default config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536157/5624578).
3. Symlink the `out` directory to base nginx directory
4. CMD to take care the production build and symlinking of the out directory.

```js
FROM node:alpine AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat git
RUN apt-get install nginx -y

WORKDIR /sample-app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /sample-app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /sample-app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /sample-app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN ls -SF /sample-app/out /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN -p 3000:80 -v /sample-app/out:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
RUN chown -R nextjs:nodejs /sample-app/out
USER nextjs

CMD ["nginx -g daemon=off"]
```

While running the docker build shell script command as `sudo docker build . -t sample-app` it throws the error `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install nginx -y' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: If you're going to install GNU libc anyways, consider a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image rather than Alpine.  For the final image also consider reusing the standard `nginx` image; you do not need Node in it once you've compiled your application to static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much experience with alpine images, but I think that you have to use `apk` (Alpine Package Keeper) for installing packages

try `apk add nginx` instead of `apt-get install nginx -y`

Comment: Thx, it works but the symlink throwing the error now.
The command '/bin/sh -c ls -SF /sample-app/out /usr/share/nginx/html' returned a non-zero code: 1